# Radio group not show when fragment change

Tags: android

I want to change fragment(@+id/content_frame) using fragment
  manager on Radiobutton (used    as a tab ) but ononCheckedChanged when fragment load
  my radio button gone it's not shown .

here is my main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/buttongroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <at.bookworm.widget.TabControlButton
            android:id="@+id/opt_ct"
            style="@style/Widget.Holo.SegmentedControl"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="City Taxi"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <at.bookworm.widget.TabControlButton
            android:id="@+id/opt_os"
            style="@style/Widget.Holo.SegmentedControl"
            android:text="Outstation"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <at.bookworm.widget.TabControlButton
            android:id="@+id/opt_lo"
            style="@style/Widget.Holo.SegmentedControl"
            android:text="Local"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RadioGroup>
    <FrameLayout  android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    style="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/silver_two"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >

    <!--
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_account"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Test"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    -->

 </ListView>

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

i replacing using fragment using fragment manager in my MainActivity 
 here is the code

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

### Fragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.buttongroup1);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(null,              FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mainFragment).commit();
        }
    });
```

}

after radio group chacked  it goes on

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

static View rootView;
------
----
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

if (rootView != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.route_fragment, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {

    }
return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to clarify this ? Is it the radio group or the button that is not displaying ? Are you reloading the UI in the new fragment ? Some code would help ...

Comment: it radiogroup used as tab button.i just replacing the fragment1 on tab clicked.

Comment: be sure about you are not changing the view

Comment: i m the beginner in android what should i do to this

Comment: ok post the code of fragment where you move after onCheckedChange of radioGroup

Comment: i just want <FrameLayout  android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> change with other view but     radio group still . after FrameLayout change with other just ajax call  for change small portion on web page

Comment: So you are changing the view, then first view disappears which has radio group

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you are doing something like this in your fragment :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
```

rather  than setContentView

This is a good resource:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html